# PHP select and insert

Tags: php

How can i minimalize that PHP code? Or write it in an easier way?

```
    $res = mysqli_query($mysqlc, "SELECT id FROM admin_szallas") or die(mysqli_error($mysqlc));
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($res)) {

    $szID = $row["id"];
    mysqli_query($mysqlc, "INSERT INTO admin_ertesitesek (szallasID, ido, uzenet, allapot, akcio) VALUES('$szID', '$ido', '$cim', '0', '$akcio')") or die(mysqli_error($mysqlc));  

}
```

Comment: minimize in what way?

Comment: I put my code to a forum and they said this is a working code, but very ugly

Comment: well, beauty is in the eye of the beholder, wouldn't you agree? ;-)

Comment: It's good for me, but if there was a lot of mysql request its not too slow? Sorry for my bad english. :/

Comment: What exactly are you trying to change here?  What's *wrong* with the code that needs to be fixed?  (Hint: Before identifying a problem *before* correcting it is usually the way to go.)  At the very least, you could do something about that SQL injection vulnerability.  That won't make the code "smaller", but it will make it "better".

Comment: yes, i want it to better

Answer (score 0):

People can see in here different problems.

1. [Coding style](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Programming_style) of presented code.
2. Usage of procedural functions instead of object-oriented.
3. Usage of `die()` instead of [`Exceptions`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.exceptions.php).

If you want to protect it from SQL Injection [check out this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php?rq=1).